# Routes are not Working giving me an error of "You cannot render a <Router> inside another <Router>. You should never have more than one in your app"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using "react-router-dom": "^6.11.2"

> Uncaught Error: You cannot render a `<Router>` inside another
> `<Router>`. You should never have more than one in your app.
>
> ```
> - at invariant (history.ts:480:
> - at Router (components.tsx:335:1)
> - at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
> - at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
> - at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
> - at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
> - at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
> - at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
> - at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1)
> - at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25850:1)]]
> ```

App.js

```
import { Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar title="TextUtils" aboutText="About TextUtils" mode={Mode} toggleMode={toggleMode} btnText={btnText} />
      <ALERTS Alert={alert} />

      <div className='container my-3'>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<TextForm heading="Enter text to analyze" mode={Mode} />} />
          <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: Are you rendering another router somewhere in the app code? If so, remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in `react-router-dom@6` when you would like to define and use `BrowserRouter`, you will need to create it as the following in your code.

```
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
} from "react-router-dom";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Root />,
    loader: rootLoader,
    children: [
      {
        path: "team",
        element: <Team />,
        loader: teamLoader,
      },
    ],
  },
]);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
   <RouterProvider router={router} />
      <App />
    </RouterProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Here is the reference: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router#createbrowserrouter

Comment: This is what you'd use to create a Data router, but it isn't required. You can still import and use `BrowserRouter` if you like. Also, the `RouterProvider` doesn't consume and render any `children` prop, so `App` in your example would be completely ignored and not rendered.